# Buying products from store that sells avodah zarah?

Tags: halacha, transactions, avodah-zarah, business

What is the Halacha on buying products (not used for [Avodah Zarah](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/682/2) and not intended) from stores that sell things that can be used for Avodah Zarah?

Assuming that buying such products is forbidden, if something was bought, and there's no way to return it, what should a Jew do with it? Donating or giving it away would further the Avodah Zarah by suggesting its use.

Comment: I don't understand "what does a Jew do with it? Donating or giving it away would further the Avodah Zarah by suggesting its use". If Walmart sells idols meant to be served (which AFAIK it doesn't, but suppose it does) and I buy a garden hose there, how would giving away the garden hose further _avoda zara_? That said, welcome to the site. I hope you stick around and enjoy it. I suggest you [register](http://mi.yodeya.com/users/login) your [account](http://mi.yodeya.com/u/1546): that will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.

Comment: "that sell things that can be used for Avodah Zarah": can't anything be used for Avoda Zara? Certainly wine can; are we not allowed to shop at any non-Jewish grocery stores?

Comment: And even if you would say that it wasn't being *sold* for a'z, many grocery stores sell candles with images of minor deities on them for catholics.

Comment: @yoel. Catholicism in theory has no "minor deities". (Catholicism [in practice](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/28/214) may have.)

Comment: @TRiG call them what you will...

Comment: DoubleAA has a great point about wine for example. So I'm guessing you would like to know about actual idols.

Comment: Could it depend on the intent of the *store* in terms of whether or not they were intentionally marketing toward an Avodah Zarah market? For example, there is an explicitly Pagan shop in my area that sells herbs, candles, and robes for use in Magickal rituals, but then one can also buy similar herbs, candles, and robes from the local grocery store and lingerie shop, and all of those items have non-Avodah Zarah uses.

Answer (score -3):

Ideally it should be forbidden because by boycotting that shop at  a collective level may help in creating a negative feeling against the avoda zarah and who knows they may even stop selling those items for the sake of a rich Jewish community?

The store could be even selling christian Idols, crosses etc and by purchasing from them you are benefiting a store which makes profits by selling idolatry.

Not just boycott it but make it vocal to please G-d

Items bought from such store should be buried away or discarded then the same value of money should be reserved to advertise against the shop selling those items.

Comment: A source would greatly improve the credibility of this answer.

Comment: Does a cross count as an idol? Especially when a lot of people use it as a decorational piece?